# Java.exe exited with code 1. Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

Trying to make archive for publishing and has this error

```
Java heap size is set to 1G.PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest

PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest

PROGUARD : warning : there were 148 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.

PROGUARD : warning : there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1833,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.
```

I made archive for publishing at Friday and everything was ok. Yesterday I have updates and installed them, but this didn't solve the problem

What's wrong?

Comment: Could you post the complete build log

Comment: Please refer my answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147828/java-exe-exited-with-code-1-proguard-issue/41355484#41355484

Answer (score 5):

Problem is solved

create file named `proguard.cfg` inside Android project in the solution. Right click and set `Build Action` to `ProguardConfig`.

I add this to proguard file

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Make sure you save file as UTF-8 and NOT UTF-8 BOM

Comment: @Koyarem your solution is not working for me...I get these errors:

8>COMPILETODALVIK : error : Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
8>COMPILETODALVIK : error : A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.