# "Java.exe" exited with code 1 (Proguard issue)

Tags: java, android, xamarin, proguard

I get the following error when I build my Xamarin.Android app in Release.

```
"Java.exe" exited with code 1
```

Here is the output...

```
...    
1> java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Users\FranciscoJavier\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar] (Can't process class [java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.class] (Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)))
1> at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:230)
1> at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:200)
1> at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:178)
1> at proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:100)
1> at proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:196)
1> at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:78)
1> at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
1> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't process class [java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.class] (Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7))
1> at proguard.io.ClassReader.read(ClassReader.java:112)
1> at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
1> at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
1> at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
1> at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
1> at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:226)
1> ... 6 more
1> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)
1> at proguard.classfile.util.ClassUtil.checkVersionNumbers(ClassUtil.java:140)
1> at proguard.classfile.io.LibraryClassReader.visitLibraryClass(LibraryClassReader.java:89)
1> at proguard.classfile.LibraryClass.accept(LibraryClass.java:301)
1> at proguard.io.ClassReader.read(ClassReader.java:86)
1> ... 11 more
1> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2118,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.
1>Done executing task "Proguard" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "_CompileToDalvikWithDx" in project "Elfo.VisionShop.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Reading the output messages it seems there is a problem with ProGuard, somebody know what can I do?

Comment: The problem is that you're compiling for Java 8, which isn't supported: `Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)`.

Comment: Ok but...how can I change this in order to compile with Java 1.7?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11364761/3788176

Comment: I do not understand that solution...

Comment: I just have checked that I already was using SDK 1.7..., as you can see: https://s31.postimg.org/xqvxi9tqz/Untitled.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Android ProGuard Enable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106663/xamarin-android-proguard-enable)

Answer (score 6):

Just update proguard from official site http://proguard.sourceforge.net/
(replace folder in $SDK_DIR/tools/proguard/)

Answer (score 4):

You can see the problem here:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't process class [java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.class] (Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7))
```

**Solution:**
Change your Java target to 7 (1.7).

Comment: install jdk 1.7 change it from File -> Project Structure

Comment: Giannisf, I did not understand you...File -> Project from where? VisualStudio? Please give me more details. Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Comment: @Fran_gg7 In Android Studio. If you are using `Xamarin`, see this post from the forums https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16210/configure-java-version-used-by-xamarin

Comment: I just have checked that I already was using SDK 1.7..., as you can see: https://s31.postimg.org/xqvxi9tqz/Untitled.png

Comment: Also make sure that you have latest proguard. default android sdk doesnt have latest proguard. you need to download and manually replace inside android sdk folder

Answer (score 3):

```
**Error : while running app “Java.exe” exited with code**
```

I resolved this by manually overriding the java heap size: In Visual Studio:

1. Right-click on *Project*
2. Click on *Android properties*
3. Click on *Android Options*
4. Select *Advanced tab* then *Advanced android build settings*
5. Set Java Max Heap Size to 1G (or larger if needed)

The project now builds.

Comment: this worked for me. If you see some error code like `-1073740791` in output this should be the solution. `-1073740791` is actually `0xC0000409`, which is actually `Stack buffer overflow`, which is ... the site's name. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem, for me the following worked (well it's a specific situation causing this error - might be not the only one):

Set Build Log verbosity to Detailed: in VS2017 -> Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run ->MSBuild project build output verbosity -> Detailed (minimum)

Start a build.
In output log (eg. in output window) search for

> proguard.ParseException:

if the log contains something like:

> proguard.ParseException: Unknown option '´╗┐-keep' in line 1 of file 'proguard.cfg'

then simply open your file in a text editor and save it without BOM.

eg. in Notepad++ Encoding -> Encode in UTF8 (make sure not to select Encode in UTF8-BOM)
...and save

Rebuild your project/solution. It should work - at least it workd for me.

Comment: You don't need to say that you know the post is old: you can answer a question (assuming it is an actual answer, which this is) whether the post is 2 minutes old, or 2 years old. Updates are periodically needed too

Comment: I noticed this error in build log but i could not figure out why it was happening. Thanks a lot for an encoding tip.