# java.exe eror (Xamarin C#)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Trying to launch app and have this error

```
"java.exe" exited with code 1.
```

I have this in output

```
    1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\\bin\java.exe -jar C:\android-sdk\tools\proguard\lib\proguard.jar -include C:\android-sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt -include obj\Release\proguard\proguard_xamarin.cfg -include obj\Release\proguard\proguard_project_references.cfg -include obj\Release\proguard\proguard_project_primary.cfg -include proguard.cfg "-injars 'obj\Release\proguard\__proguard_input__.jar';'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\mono.android.jar';'obj\Release\__library_projects__\Square.OkHttp\library_project_imports\okhttp.jar';'obj\Release\__library_projects__\Square.OkIO\library_project_imports\okio-1.6.0.jar';'obj\Release\__library_projects__\Square.Picasso\library_project_imports\picasso-2.5.2.jar';'obj\Release\__library_projects__\UrlImageViewHelper\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'C:\Users
1>emes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.4.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users
1>emes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.4.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users
1>emes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.4.0.0\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.4.0.jar';'C:\Users
1>emes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.4.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users
1>emes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.4.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users
1>emes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.4.0.0\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.4.0.jar';'C:\Users
1>emes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.4.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users
1>emes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users
1>emes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users
1>emes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar'" "-libraryjars 'C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar'" -outjars "obj\Release\proguard\__proguard_output__.jar" 
1>"java.exe" exited with code 1.
1>Build FAILED.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I have experienced this as well, however don't remember exactly what I did. But my suggestion - check if you have just one JDK installed (so it's not 1.6 + 1.7), uninstall the one that you don't want to use (Xamarin does not like having two on the same machine). If that fails, look into updating to 1.8 :)

Comment: Have this now @JakubHolovsky

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Java.exe" exited with code 1 (Proguard issue)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147828/java-exe-exited-with-code-1-proguard-issue)