# 'Java.exe' exited with code 1 when i enable Sdk Assemmblies Only in Release mode

Tags: xamarin

I'm able to compile my App in **'Sdk Assemblies Only'** if **'Enable Pro Guard'** and **'Enable Multi Dex'** are ticked off. As soon as i tick them on then i get an error message that says **'Java.exe' exited with code 1**. What could be the possible cause ?

Please see the screen shot below :

[image]

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147828/java-exe-exited-with-code-1-proguard-issue

Comment: Increasing Heap size to 1G fixed my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manually overrid the java heap size:

```
>     In Xamarin Studio:
>     Right-click on Project
>     Options
>     Android Build
>     Advanced
>     Set Java Heap Size to 1G
```

And This also helped to me

> ref - https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/230873/#Comment_230873
>
> downloaded the proguard file and unzip it
> url to download file
> https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/4.6/
> go to this location:
>
> C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools
>
> here you will find proguard folder rename it to proguard.old
>
> and paste the downloaded unzip folder(folder with name proguard) there
> inside the tools folder. rebuilt and run project,
>
> after doing this if you won't get the solution do the last step also
> last step is: open the proguard.old folder copy all files from here
> and paste in the proguard folder(skip the same files if you get the
> warning)
>
> Note :Everything you need to do inside this location only
> C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools

Read this article for learn more - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/release-prep/proguard/

Comment: Increasing Heap size to 1G fixed my issue. Thank you.